# Adjoint of unitary operator U such that U−I is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra

> Suppose $V$ is a $\mathbb{C}$-vector space with $\dim V<\infty$, and $U:V→V$ is a unitary operator such that $U−I$ is invertible. Show that
>   $$T=−i(U+I)(U−I)^{-1}$$ is adjoint.

Any idea?

I try to see $T=T^*$ and $\langle T(u),v\rangle=\langle u,T^*(v)\rangle$. But does not reach anything.
Thanks so much.

Comment: Did you mean $T = -i(U+I)(U-I)-1$ or $T = -i(U+I)(U-I)^{-1}$? Also, you should probably say explicitly what "its" is referring to in the last sentence. (Do you mean $U$ here?)

Comment: @Dan thanks, I corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $U$ is unitary, we have

$$T = -i(U+UU^*)(U-UU^*)^{-1} = -i U(I+U^*)U^{-1}(I-U^*)^{-1} = i(I+U^*)(U^*-I)^{-1} = T^*.$$

Comment: i lacked try write $I=UU^*$. thanks so much

Comment: @user89940 sorry, but the last equal is an inequal, becouse $(ToR)^{*}=R^{*} o T^{*}$, so $T^{*}=i(U^{*} - I)^{-1} (U^{*} + I)$.

Comment: Note that $U$ is normal, hence everything commutes here...